# Treeview receives unidentified notification

Tags: winapi, treeview

I was using [Control Spy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773165(v=vs.85).aspx) to check out certain characteristics of the treeview control with checkboxes.

I was observing what happens when user presses <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, so I watched for `TVN_KEYDOWN` notification. All of a sudden, just after `TVN_KEYDOWN` notification, I saw undefined notification `0xffffffe8`.

Can someone tell me more about this notification, and what is it used for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xffffffe8` corresponds to [`NM_TVSTATEIMAGECHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775572(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Sent by a tree-view control to its parent window that the state image
>   is changing. This notification code is sent in the form of a WM_NOTIFY
>   message.

Why Microsoft used an `NM_xxx` code instead of `TVN_xxx` I have no idea.

Comment: Strangely enough, this message is not listed in official treeview documentation so I have missed it. The structure that goes along with it is though... Thank you, upvoted and officially accepted. Best regards.